# Are all curried functions considered higher-order functions?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, definition, currying

If you take the definition from wikipedia of a higher-order function, it is a function which either takes another function as an argument and/or returns another function.

From my (limited) understanding, a curried function intermediately returns another function in order to accept another argument; opposed to accepting two (or more) arguments at the same time. So would this make all curried functions higher-order?
More to the point, if they are considered higher-order, *are they generally referred to as such?*

This may be an obvious question but I am learning Haskell and can't seem to find an explicit answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it depends on your definition of "curried". *Currying* is the process of turning a function of type `(a, b) -> c` into  function of type `a -> b -> c`. Is a function of type `Int -> Int` curried? You can't produce it from the process of currying, but neither can you *apply* currying to it, so maybe it's "fully curried" in a vacuous sense?

Comment: I've seen someone here argue that a simple function type like `Int -> Int -> Int` should not be considered a higher-order function, though I don't know if the problem is with *only* the return type being a function, or the return type not itself being a higher-order function type. (Would `a -> (b -> c) -> d` be considered a higher-order function? Strictly speaking, it takes a non-function argument, but its informal "second" argument is a function.)

Comment: @chepner My favorite would be to follow the definition of rank for types. The "rank" of a type is how many times you can go to the left of an arrow and see a forall. I want the "order" of a type to be how many times you can go to the left of an arrow. So `Int -> Int -> Int` has order 1 (possible paths are [left], [right, left], and [right, right], which each have at most 1 left), while `a -> (b -> c) -> d` has order 2 (possible paths are [left], [right, left, left], [right, left, right], [right, right]). Polymorphism is a wrinkle, but not a killer one. Alas, we do not live in that timeline.

Comment: (One nice property of this proposed definition is that currying and uncurrying do not change the order of a type, if you add some suitable rules about descending into products and sums in your paths.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, If you take the definition from Wikipedia then yes: All curried functions are higher-order. Of course, that has the effect that most haskell functions are indeed higher-order (at least functions with two+ arguments defined idiomatially)

Now, if you take any learning resource you'll find that curried functions aren't refered as higher-order. Instead a HOF is one that takes a function as argument. *Strictly* speaking curried functions have only one argument, therefore:

```hs
not_higher_order :: a -> a -> a
higher_order :: (a -> a) -> a
```

Notice that the with the definition above the following function isn't a HOF because its argument is not a function.

```hs
-- the argument isn't a function but it returns
-- a a function which first argument is.
not_higher_order? :: a -> (a -> a) -> a
```

So most resources would say that a HOF is one that accepts another function in any of its arguments accepting that `f :: a -> a -> a` has two arguments instead of one.

So in summary, within haskell's jargon and learning materials a HOFs are referred *informally* as those which any of its parameters is a function (where *its parameters* is not the best phrase, but everybody understand). This definition does not follow wikipedia's

Comment: I've never heard anyone say there's a difference between the first and later arguments for categorizing HOFs. You'd say that `fmap` is a HOF, but `(>>=)` isn't? That's mad. What resources did you consult that led you to say that "In the haskell's jargon HOF are those in which the first parameter is a function"?

Comment: @amalloy In the last paragraph is stated "HOF are those which any of its parameters is a function". The problem is that all haskell functions has _just one parameter_, so technically It doesn't make sense to talk about the _second argument_. Therefore, if we follow [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Higher_order_function) definition: _takes other functions as arguments_ it can be **only** _takes a function as first argument_

Comment: OP is precisely confuse about that: if you follow wikipedia's defiinition, things like `(+)` are indeed HOF because it is curried. Probably I should rephrase that part to distinguish between the technicallity and the jargon better. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Even the haskell wiki entry you link to implies it disagrees with you. It writes "returns **a function**", singular, but "takes **other functions as arguments**", plural: it's talking in terms of multi-argument functions. Of course, at a low level of abstraction, all Haskell functions take just one parameter. But people talk all the time about multi-parameter functions, and nobody (except occasionally beginners) is confused about what we mean. And its `operlist` example takes its function in the *second* argument, not the first.

Comment: I like to think that Haskell's syntax and semantics unify the concepts of "an N-argument function" and "a 1-argument function that returns an (N-1)-argument function". I say they are 2 different ways of describing the exact same thing, not that one viewpoint is "real" and the other is not. But if you're using the "all functions are single-argument" viewpoint, then a more appropriate definition of a higher-order function is something like "a function that takes a function as its argument, or returns a higher-order function as result". (1/2)

Comment: And when you're using the multi-argument-function viewpoint, then a better definition is that a HOF is a function that accepts a function as any argument. Either view is perfectly fine, but taking conclusions from one viewpoint and applying it in the other viewpoint without appropriate translation produces nonsense. Don't take a definition clearly intended for the multi-argument viewpoint and apply it to the "all functions are single-argument" world view. (2/2)

Comment: @amalloy. That is exactly what my answer says. Notice that OP knows what currification is and OP is confused about interactions with HOF's definition, so I tried to explicitly state: "most haskellers will refer functions as multiparameter and HOF if one of those parameters is a function", but you have to deal first with the fact that multiparameter functions are yet another made up concept and that's kind of the source of OP's confusion

Comment: @Ismor I get the impression that the question I asked is very dependant on quite an ambiguous definition. But you are absolutely right that my focus is more on what most Haskellers refer to it as. The part of your answer you quote in the above comment is what I was looking for (provided most others would agree with you), and I appreciate that. What I take away from this is that yes, all curried functions are HOF, but no, they are not all definitively referred to as such, and the HOF definition is used more loosely in the Haskell community for clarity's sake. Correct me if my takeaway is wrong.

Comment: You are right. I would say "Yes, curried functions are HOF and in most programming languages they are refered as so. Whereas in Haskell-world the definition is relaxed to fit the language better". By the way, notice that the definition of HOF used in Haskell is a perfectly valid one in the sense that can be formally defined. I don't think the formal definition really matters if we all understand the _informal_ one tougth...

Answer (score 3):

The informal concept that we're trying to capture in the term "higher-order function" is a function that computes with functions in some sense, rather than computing with simple data.

In the "I know it when I see it" sense, `map` is "obviously" a higher-order function because it receives an arbitrary function as argument and uses it as a function. While integer addition is obviously not.

We can formalise this idea by coming up with a precise definition for what is and isn't a higher-order function. But for that term to be *useful* it needs to capture a class of functions that actually matches reasonably well what we were thinking of with the informal concept.

The wikipedia article is trying to talk about the concept in general, not specifically in the context of Haskell. But Haskell does one thing that is very relevant to this discussion on a way that is very different from many other languages. Haskell syntax unifies the concept of a multi-argument function and a function that returns a function.

In C-like syntax, you can easily tell the difference between a binary function and it's curried variant:

```
int plus(int x, int y) {
   return x + y;
}

function(int -> int) plusCurried(x) {
   return function(y) {
     return x + y;
   }
}
```

Not only are `plus` and `plusCurried` written differently, they have distinguished types and you have to call them differently; `plus(1, 2)` vs `plusCurried(1)(2)`.

Whereas in Haskell syntax the two have the same type and you can't tell them apart from the outside (you call them the same way, and nothing in the language can tell you whether the function was implemented internally by taking fewer explicit arguments and explicitly returning a function). In a way, currying (and uncurrying) a Haskell function is a no-op. Nothing observable changes. It's common to say that all functions are curried in Haskell, but Haskell simply has no syntax for expressing the distinction between curried and uncurried functions, at least from the outside. (We can simulate that by wrapping arguments into a tuple, but all the language mechanics see that as a single argument because a tuple is a first class value in itself).

The reason I bring this up is that in languages without this syntactic fusion between curried and uncurried functions, it *does* make some sense to call `plusCurried` a higher-order function. Somebody *explicitly* wrote it as a function-generating function instead of writing the much simpler `plus`, and expected all users to be aware of that. So putting it on the higher-order side is drawing a useful distinction between types of functions. In languages like this the definition "a higher order function is one that takes functions as arguments or returns a function as a result" is a useful definition.

Haskell though is a bit different. *All* functions of more than one argument can be used as function-generators. So if we put them all in the higher-order camp just because they can be viewed as functions-that-return-functions, then the term "higher-order function" isn't drawing a very useful distinction.

Additionally, it is supposed to be purely an implementation detail whether a function implementation was written in a function-returning style or by directly receiving all arguments; this doesn't "leak out" into the type or the syntax you need to call the function. So implementers are free to use either style for their own implementation convenience; it's not an interface concern, and probably shouldn't change which side of the higher-order divide the function is on, or again the term would just not be drawing a very useful distinction.

Polymorphism is another wrinkle. `id` of course has most general type `a -> a`, but it *can* be used at type `(Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)`. Does it change whether it's higher-order based on the context in which it's used?

So generally no, Haskellers don't strictly use a definition of higher-order function as any function that takes or returns functions and conclude that any curried function is higher-order. It's just not useful to use the term that way. But I don't criticise the Wikipedia article's definition; it's not an article about Haskell.

A better definition specifically for Haskell would be something like that "a higher order function has at least one argument that is a function" if you're viewing Haskell types with multiple arrows as multi-argument functions. If you're viewing types with multiple arrows as single argument functions that return other functions, then a better definition would be something like "a higher order function is one that takes a function as its argument *or* returns a higher order function" (this is recursive of course, but that's hardly out of character for Haskell).  A nice quirk of Haskell syntax is that either view is correct, because it fuses the concepts into the same thing.

You may or may not want to complicate your definition to account for functions that receiver other functions inside data structures. Is `[a -> b] -> a -> [b]` a higher-order function type? What about `F a b -> a -> [b]`, where `F` is an opaque type that seems to contain functions based on its exported interface?

Answer (score 1):

> Would this make all curried functions higher-order?

**Yes.** Formally, `A -> B -> C` ≡ `A -> (B -> C)` is a unary function type of order 2. So is the type of `map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])`.

> More to the point, if they are considered higher-order, are they generally referred to as such?

**No.** Informally, `A -> B -> C` is a binary function type, because it can accept 2 arguments; and it has order 1, because it’s equivalent to an order-1 type `(A, B) -> C`, assuming the function is total. Whereas the type of `map` has a minimum order of 2 in Haskell.